# Regex exclude letter

Tags: regex

I have regex pattern `(^\w+\W\w+)` which parse string such like:

```
in-package :presenter-domain
test-re :type string :display ""
name-de :type string :display ""
```

How to exclude variants when word starting with letter `i`.

I tried something like `[^i]` but it does not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use a negative lookahead:

```
(?!i)(^\w+\W\w+)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/pI4hC6/1)

Comment: but if i have something like (^\w+\W\w+\W\w+)|(^\w+\W\w+)|(^\w+). Where should i place negative lookahead for each contruction?

Comment: either at the start and enclose the rest of the expression in parens, or before each alternation - i.e. `(?!i)(?:(^\w+\W\w+\W\w+)|(^\w+\W\w+)|(^\w+))` or `(?!i)(^\w+\W\w+\W\w+)|(?!i)(^\w+\W\w+)|(?!i)(^\w+)`

Comment: or, alternatively, don't repeat yourself: `^(?!i)(\w+)(\W\w+){0,2}`

Comment: or something like :--(?!i)((^\w+\W\w+\W\w+)|(^\w+\W\w+)|(^\w+))